# CSS - Nth-of-type and class

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
span {
    color: purple;
}
.title {
    color: blue;
}
.title:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="title">Test #1</span>
<span>Some text</span>
<span class="title">Test #2</span>
```

In the above simple example, why is the text `Test #2` not in `red` color? It is the second child of a parent and is declared as a `title` class too. If I delete the second row `<span>Some text</span>`, it is selected though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in css. You can style a specific element by it tag (e.g.`<p>`) but you can't style a specified element by counting its class. This happens because CSS selects the `<p>` element that is the specified appearance of the paragraph type within its parent and it skips other elements when counting. But this is not possible to count elements with a certain class name.

So as described above this isn't possible in CSS. **If you are looking for a CSS only answer and based on your markup you can do something like this**.

Example 1

```
.title ~ .title {
   color: red;
}
```

Example 2

```
span:nth-of-type(3) {
   color: red;
}
```

**Here is a [great article](https://medium.com/better-programming/css-select-nth-element-with-class-a313d080e2bf) on this topic.**

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with JS.
I hope I have been helpful

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
x[1].setAttribute("style", "color: red;");
```

```html
<span class="title">Test #1</span>
<span>Some text</span>
<span class="title">Test #2</span>
```

Comment: Or `let x = document.querySelectorAll("title");` and then `x[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Answer (score 0):

.title:nth-of-type(2) means while it is 2nd type element, and it have a title class.

but This has no effect, because the  `.title` class is on the 3th span element, not the 2nd.

but if you remove the second element, the `.title` class becomes 2nd element, so `:nth-of-type(2)` works on the text `Test #2`

**to make it easy**

when webpage see this code `.title:nth-of-type(2)`

```
<span class="title">Test #1</span>
<span>Some text</span>
<span class="title">Test #2</span>
```

let's see what is the element it have a class `.title`?

oh there's two!
first and third.

but because of this `:nth-of-type(2)` it have to be a second type element.

oh it is this --> `<span>Some text</span>`
huh, but it doesn't have a `.title` class!

--> **so no element got selected**

Comment: But if I delete the `<span>Some text</span>` part, it is selected though.

Comment: sorry @darkchampionz I edited it

Answer (score 0):

**Structural pseudo-classes**
[W3.ORG](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#nth-child-pseudo)
Selectors introduces the concept of structural pseudo-classes to permit selection based on extra information **that lies in the document tree but cannot be represented by other simple selectors or combinators.**

Standalone text and other non-element nodes are not counted when calculating the position of an element in its list of siblings; index numbering starts at 1.

According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

**The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches elements of a given type (tag name), based on their position among a group of siblings.**

That means it high [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for   take to  matches elements . for the reason it will not work.. if you want expected result you need to write below code..

```
title:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: red !important;
}
```

The nth-of-type pseudo-class is specified with a single argument, which represents the pattern for matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a class with the nth-of-type() selector. You can only set its parent.
Suppose if I say {.title:nth-of-type(odd)}, then we are selecting all those parent elements which are odd in the count and have class as "title".

### Now, in your case:

```
   By {.title:nth-of-type(2)}, it understands that you are selecting 2nd of the type span(which is the parent here) and which have class as "title".
```

So no element will get selected here.
I hope you understood.

Answer (score -1):

according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

> The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches elements of a given type (tag name), based on their position among a group of siblings. :nth-of-type(  )
> where
>  =  | even | odd

so you need to change your css code from

```
span {
    color: purple;
}
.title {
    color: blue;
}
.title:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

to bellow code

```
span {
    color: purple;
}
.title {
    color: blue;
}
.title:nth-of-type(3n) {
    color: red;
}
```

the second way you can do.

```
span {
    color: purple;
}
.title {
    color: blue;
}
.title:not(:first-child) {
    color: red;
}
```